# What is a workaround for placing a background image in Gmail?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I understand gmail does not support `background-images` or `background: url('..` in Gmail. I was wondering if anyone had a sizeable workaround to this?

This is for emails I send via a server to a user's email accounts if they are using gmail.

Comment: What do you mean "in Gmail"? Do you mean HTML E-Mails viewed in GMail?

Comment: Yes I do. I updated the question above.

Comment: As a Gmail user, I am very thankful that I don't see anyone's background images.

Comment: probably belongs on webapps.se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice cheatsheet I use for creating webbased emails. Support for background-images isn't widely supported, so I avoid it anyway.

[Cheatsheet for CSS support in EMAIL clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

This file says that background is "buggy", so there might be some elements that do support background-images for gmail. For instance, you can try a table-cell with a background images. In my experience, for email-templates tables are the best option (I wish it was different)...

Comment: So in conclusion, there really is no way to get background images in gmail..

Comment: My point is, that you can test if a td-element can use a background image. If not, then I'm out of ideas...

Some googling gave me this site: [website about background-images in email](http://mailchimp.blogs.com/blog/2006/01/background_imag.html)

Comment: A little late to the discussion, but I can confirm that setting the html background property on a td element worked for me in Gmail.

Comment: Better late then never! Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the standard CSS background-image you need to add this to a table using the background="" the webpage below gives a clear explanation.

http://blog.exacttarget.com/blog/design-tip-of-the-week-hotmail-in-firefox/email-design-tip-of-the-week-gmail-takes-two-steps-forward-and-one-step-back